# Rewrite a folder based on another folder name using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

There are urls which are coming as following

1) https://localhost/asset/uploads/folder/pictures/students/thumbnails/1537956127.png?1537955969

2) https://localhost/asset/uploads/folder1/pictures/bus/thumbnails/1537956127.png?1537955969

3) https://localhost/asset/uploads/folder2/pictures/monitor/thumbnails/1537956127.png?1537955969

If any of url does not contain **students** as sub folder i need to redirect to specific folder after uploads folder.

For example the 2 and 3  should be

2) https://localhost/asset/uploads/new_folder/pictures/bus/thumbnails/1537956127.png?1537955969

3)https://localhost/asset/uploads/new_folder/pictures/monitor/thumbnails/1537956127.png?1537955969

from **folder1** and **folder2** to **new_folder**

How to achieve it efficiently using .htaccess' RewriteCond and RewriteRule ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/students/
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)/pictures/(.*)$ /uploads/new_folder/pictures/$2 [L]
```

This should do the trick.

First we enable the rewrite engine and set the base to the /-start of the url.
Then we say that if the `folder or filename` was not found at the original location AND the url doesn't have students anywhere in the path we want to rewrite.
then the folder1 is edited to new_folder.

In this case, because of the rewrite instead of a redirect, the client will not see the rewrite and will still see `folder1` in the url while the file shown is located at  `new_folder` on the server.

I have edited the answer so folder1 can be dynamic. I do assume here that you always use uploads and pictures in the path.

Comment: Thanks for your response, The tricky part is that folder1 is not always same name, it might come like folder2, folder3. We need to replace these folders to new_folder based on condition(which contains students in url).

Comment: @user3391137 I have edited the response for the use of dynamic folder names.